# Is placing student work term reviews on my online portfolio okay when applying for part time jobs?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications

I'm a CS student entering my third year of university. I am in a Co-op program, and finished two work terms. I am now applying for part time web developer/IT positions at my university (in a work-study program where full time students can apply for part time jobs related to their field) so that I can ensure I have enough money to pay off 4th year.

I have an online "portfolio" to showcase my web skills. I have an `about me` section (brief summary of me), an `education` section (where I mention a list of relevant courses I completed first and second year), and a `portfolio` section where I have a list of projects I worked on for school / software developed during courses. But since most of my CS courses are math, I only have 2 significant software related projects to showcase. **Is it okay if I fill this area up with my work term 1 and 2 review?**

Basically, as a web/IT manager going through applications, **would you want to see a students previous work term review in the "portfolio" section of his website when hiring for part time job?**

Or is it something which **should be saved when asked for references / questioned about previous employers during or after an interview?**

**Edits:** I will be applying with a resume, and a link to my online portfolio will be on my resume. Also, my co-op work terms are related to the part time jobs I will be applying for.

Comment: which country is this?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Toronto, ON, Canada.

Comment: Ok... and by "term review" you mean? Other projects you have worked but not related to software development *per se*?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I worked as a web developer during a co-op work term (a full time contract position lasting 4-8 months offered to students so that students can develop experience related to their field before graduating). Every student is given a review by their supervisor of how they did during their co-op work term (ranked from 1-5 on dependability, efficiency, hard work, ability to get along with others etc and a brief comment made by the supervisor about the student regarding work ethic). My supervisors review of how I did during my stay at the company is what I mean when saying "term review".

Comment: I see you further edited your question, I will edit my answer to better fit your post...

Comment: Your first question should probably be "would anyone even look at an online portfolio I link to from my resume", and the answer to that is "probably not".

Comment: Almost duplicate - [Is it appropriate to include some quotes from my manager's evaluation in my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62322/is-it-appropriate-to-include-some-quotes-from-my-managers-evaluation-in-my-resu)

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, as a web / IT manager going through applications, would you want to see a students previous work term review in the "portfolio" section of his website when hiring for part time job? ...

First of all I consider that someone looking to hire new recruits (being developers or not) is more likely to expect a **Resume**, or if more detail is needed a **CV** (*Curriculum Vitae*). Do not expect that person to **browse through your personal website** in search for the information they seek.

Regarding your question, **yes** you could fit those Term Reviews in your portfolio, as they are related to the jobs you apply.

The Term Reviews could also go **in your CV instead**. I would not recommend adding them to your Resume, as it should stay concise and efficient in showing your skills. If you *can* paraphrase the review in a few lines (like "Excellent work during all time worked") then you could add them.

However, I would refrain from adding anything in my Resume if it is not related to the job you seek.

**Note:** Please refer to [What is the difference between a resume and a CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-difference-between-a-resume-and-a-cv) for a better description of what a resume and a CV are.

> ... Or is it something which should be saved when asked for references / questioned about previous employers during or after an interview?

I would say **yes**. During an interview is probably the best moment you can show them your personal website, as they have more time to look at it in detail and ask you follow-up questions about it.

---

**So bottom line**: I recommend you *create a Resume* so you can use it to efficiently and concisely draw the attention of possible recruiters (Your edit says you already have one, good).

You website you can *mention during interviews*, so they get more detailed information about you if prompted for evidence. Also, for those things you consider not related to the jobs you seed you could add them in a *new tab* more proper to their nature, like "Miscellaneous" or "Other works".

Comment: I edited my answer and added new options for your website... those reviews could go in a new tab more proper to their nature as explained in the answer

Comment: Okay thanks (I am applying with a resume and my website is linked on my resume). By "You website you can (should) mention during interviews, so they get more detailed information about you" do you mean I should mention the website during the interview?

Comment: Is something you could mention if they ask for a backup on what you say your skills are, as a way to prove them "see, I did worked on this and my review was good", editing the answer

Comment: I don't agree that performance reviews should be included on either a resume or a CV. I think you're reading too much into the differences between a resume and a CV (and I can't help but feel like you largely included that section because the question is featured).

Comment: Not only from the feature questions (and chats), this question was somehow related to that topic.. I said he *could* add those in the cv. He was also mainly asking if he should add those to the *webpage*, somewhere more fit for those details.

Comment: Note that in the post you linked to somewhat conflicts with the advice you gave - the answers largely indicate that the differences between a "resume" and a "CV" are not nearly as black and white as you seem to indicate, and often there is no difference.